# where clause for array on mongo does not work

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb, I have a document in my db as follow:

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "546e916cd38e0b3e0e79592f"} , "name" : "hamed" , "entity" : [ "1" , "2"]}

Now I want to read aal docs that entity=["1","2"]
for that I tried the following code :

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
    Set<String> colls = db.getCollectionNames();
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("test");
    DBObject oredrFields = new BasicDBObject();
    oredrFields.put("entity", ":{ $in: ['1', '2'] } }");
    DBCursor cursor = coll.find(oredrFields);
    try {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
```

But it does not return anything... Can anyone help how I can write my where clause correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your query parameters as `DBObject`. You are missing an `DBObject` for the `$in` operator.

If you want only those records that have both "1" and "2", you need to use `$all` instead of  `$in`, which returns only those documents whose `entity` field contain `all` the elements in the passed array.

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("test");
    DBObject oredrFields = new BasicDBObject();
    DBObject inQuery = new BasicDBObject().append("$all", new String[]{"1","2"});
    oredrFields.put("entity", inQuery);
    DBCursor cursor = coll.find(oredrFields);
    try {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

$in should be a BasicDBObject as well:

```
DBObject oredrFields = new BasicDBObject();
DBObject inOp = new BasicDBObject();
inOp .put("$in", new String[]{"1","2"});
oredrFields.put("entity", inOp);
```